# Prove function (0, ∞) to (0, ∞) can't exist if $(f(x))^2>(f(x+y))((f(x)+y))$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

So we're trying to prove that no function exists $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow(0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)^2\ge f(x+y) (f(x)+y)\quad x,y\gt0$

I've tried to break it up into 3 cases to show if $x\gt y$ and  $x\lt y$ and $x= y$ to show that $f(x+y)\gt f(x)$, but doesn't that depend on the initial function? i.e $\frac{1}{x}\gt\frac{1}{x+y}$ not $\lt$ like I wanted to show.

I'm just stumped at how to prove this for any function.

We've tried to set it all up on one side and do the quadratic equation to try and chase down a numerical value to prove that $f(x+y)\gt f(x)$ so we could then say that $f(x+y)f(x)\gt f(x)f(x)$ which would imply that $f(x+y)f(x)\gt f(x)^2$ so our original function of $f(x)^2\ge((f(x+y))((f(x)+y))$ could be rewritten as $f(x)^2\ge((f(x))^2+f(x+y)y)$ which we know $f(x)^2 \lt f(x)^2 + y$ so we'd have a contradiction.

But I can never seem to figure out how to write a formal proof of the ideas I have. If my idea was even a valid idea. Thanks ahead of time!

Just had an idea to find some value such that it is always contradictory like choosing $y=x^2-x$, but then $y$ could have a negative value so I'm going to have to find a new y=, but that's the path I'm going now!

Comment: Where does this question come from?  For example, if it comes from a book, knowing what the chapter is about could give a clue as to what tools you could use to gain some traction.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that any $f$ that satisfies the inequality must necessarily be a monotonically decreasing function on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: This problem came from a class that really isn't one subject. It's like a degree (BA) ending class that is suppose to only use things that you would have learned in the first 1.5-2 years of your undergraduate degree. He says were should know how to do all of the steps involved and if we use something that didn't come from the time frame given then we'd have to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the proof is as follows. $f(x)$ is decreasing positive function with the limit $0$ at infinity. We try to show that with the inequality stated above, $f(x)$ decreases so fast that it cannot stay all the time above zero.

---

First observe that $f$ is monotonically decreasing:
$$
(f(x))^2\geq f(x+y)((f(x)+y))\geq f(x+y)f(x)\implies f(x)\geq f(x+y)
$$

Secondly observe that:
$$
(f(x))^2\geq f(x+y)((f(x)+y))\geq f(x+y)y\implies f(x+y)\leq \frac{f(x)^2}{y}
$$
Therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$.

Now because $f$ is monotonically decreasing, it has countable point of discontinuities. Suppose for the rest that the values of $x,y$ are chosen in the set of continuities of $f$, denoted by $\mathcal C$. $f$ is over $\mathcal C$ differentiable. We have:
$$
\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}+\frac{f(x+y)}{f(x)}\leq 0
$$
When $y\to 0$ for $x\in\mathcal C$, we have:
$$
f'(x)+1\leq 0.
$$
Therefore $g(x)=f(x)+x$ is decreasing on $\mathcal C$ and because $f(x)$ and $x$ are positive, therefore $g(x)\geq 0$, bounded from below and hence it should converge to $L<\infty$ when $x\to\infty$. But:
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)+\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}x=0+\infty=\infty
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: how does the "secondly observe that:" come into play? Do we need to even include that part? and should the Therefore "lim x to infinty of f(x)=0" be "lim y to infinity of f(x)=0"

Comment: We need an argument for saying that the function is bounded at infinity. As for your next question, the inequality shows that $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(x+y)=0$ for a given $x$, which is same as $ $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$.